# Firefox WebExtention executeScript runAt ignorance

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing small WebExtention for Firefox browser. It turns out Firefox handles the `runAt` property differently for content scripts from *manifest.json* vs. from `browser.tabs.executeScript` method.

*content-script.js*:

```js
console.log('content script fired!');
```

background script *settings-script.js*:

```js
function handleUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) {
    var pageVar = "console.log('executeScript fired!'); 
    var executing = browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        code: pageVar,
        runAt: "document_start"
    });
}

browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleUpdated);
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUpdated);
```

*test-page.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test my behaviour</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('start very first page script');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*manifest.json*:

```json
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "storage",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*", 
  "https://*/*",
  "file://*/*"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background/settings-script.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
```

The console output looks like this:

```
'content script fired!'
'start very first page script'
'executeScript fired!'
```

So, why does Firefox ignore my `runAt` property and keep executing script on `document_idle` when I inject it with `tabs.executeScript()` programmatically?

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I suggest you look at when the various events fire that are available wrt. when a page/tab updates/is created/webRequests/webNavigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, why does Firefox ignore my runAt property and keep executing script on document_idle when I inject it with tabs.executeScript() programmatically?

It does not. It's just too late - you're in a race with the page.

`tabs.executeScript` will honor `runAt` as the *earliest* opportunity to run a script. But by the time your `executeScript` actually runs, the page has already fully loaded.

Consider this: with scripts defined in `manifest.json`, Chrome knows in advance that some script has to precede the page loading.

On the other hand, `tabs.onCreated`/`tabs.onUpdated` fire at some point after creation/update started. There is a natural processing delay, while the page merrily continues to load - it's not an event that blocks until all extensions decided what to do. And when you call the `executeScript` API, it again takes some time for Chrome to adjust its internal machinery.

All the while your trivial page ends loading already. For a slow-loading page you may see difference, but not with one you show as a test.

---

A *proper* solution to decide, at runtime, what scripts to include *in advance* does not really exist. `chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript` is, in theory, supposed to allow that - but it's not supported even in stable Chrome builds, and certainly not in Firefox.

If you need to implement some conditional logic in `document_start` scripts, it's very hard - you can't do anything asynchronously, so `chrome.storage` and Messaging do not help.

Comment: turns out it is FFox **OSX** behavior, recently I've tested it on Win8 - everything works as expected with no problems. So now I'm stuck and even don't know where to address this issue.

Comment: As it's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), it's normal to see inconsistent results based on many factors. My point is, you can't make it consistent though `executeScript`.